# Working out the math for adding the right amount of an item to ML to make 100ml

Tags: calculus

Can anyone give me a hand with the following math ?

I want to make 100ml of a liquid product. I have the liquid already in a larger quantity.

The total of 100ml needs to the final product.

The total of 100ml needs to contain 3mg of an additive product.

The additive product is 20mg per ml.

So how do i work out how much to add to the final product so that total is 100ml and contains 3mg of the additive product that actual is 20mg per ml.

Any ideas ?

I am not sure on the math.

If anyone can help, with each step - that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$3$ mg of additive is contained in $\frac{3}{20} = 0.15$ ml of the additive. So if you mix $99.85$ ml of the liquid with $0.15$ ml of the additive, you'll have $100$ ml of solution with $3$ mg of additive.

Comment: Thanks., but dont you need to then multiple by 100 to set 15ml ? That 0.15 would be for 1 mil right ? So you need to multiply by 100 to get the value for 100ml?

Comment: No. The additive's density is $20mg/ml$ right? So $3mg$ is contained in $0.15$ ml

Comment: yes the additive density is 20mg/ml pero the final product needs to have 3mg total.. so 100ml has 3mg total